# Setting progress of TbHtml::stackedProgressBar inside a TbGridView column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have a `TbGridview` which displays some data using a `CActiveDataProvider` source. Code is as follows:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'type' => 'striped bordered condensed small',
        'id' => 'event-grid',
        'template' => '{items}',
        'dataProvider' => Event::model()->getAssignedEvents(),
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Event Name',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode("$data->name"),
                                        array("//callround/index","event"=>$data->event_id))',
            ),
            array(
                'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '100'),
                'name' => 'Progress',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => function() {
                    echo TbHtml::stackedProgressBar(array(
                    array('color' => TbHtml::PROGRESS_COLOR_SUCCESS, 'width' => 35),
            ));
        },
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

First column has a URL and second column has a TbHtml::stackedProgressBar. I have hard-coded the percentage of the progress bar (as 35) & it looks like this at the moment.

[image]

I can't figure out a way to set the progress percentage dynamically. I have a function get the progress as follows:

```
function GetCallroundProgress($event_id)
```

I want to dynamically set the progress in a way, possibly as follows:

```
 echo TbHtml::stackedProgressBar(array(
                    array('color' => TbHtml::PROGRESS_COLOR_SUCCESS,
 'width' => GetCallroundProgress($event_id)),
```

But how can I get the `event_id` within the `TbGridView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it was a rather stupid question. But I'll anyway post the answer so some noob like me would find it useful someday.

In my code I have to pass the `$data` variable in to the function where I draw the progress bar:

```
array(
                'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '100'),
                'name' => 'Progress',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => function($data) {
                    echo TbHtml::stackedProgressBar(array(
                    array('color' => TbHtml::PROGRESS_COLOR_SUCCESS, 'width' => Globals::GetCallroundProgress($data->event_id)),
            ));
        },
            ),
```

Then I can use whatever value `$data` holds within the function- In my case I can use

`$data->event_id`